# Azure backup configuration - Change from Geo to Local (greyed out)

Tags: azure, backup, recovery, redundancy, dpm

I'm using DPM to azure online backup and I want to change the redundancy from Geo to Local, but it's greyed out. Is there a way to change it?

[image]

I don't want to create a new fault just for that, then I have to re-upload everything from DPM to azure again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change after the initial configuration. If you want to change the configuration you have to rebuild the Backup vault and register the servers. I had the same issue at a customer in the past.

Comment: This isn't the place to promote your blog and redirect Q&A to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this before you protect your first item. You can create a vault, change the settings and even change it after you registered your DPM server. Once you started protecting, you cannot change the replication settings for vault storage.